# How do I configure APT proxy correctly?

Tags: apt, security, proxy

I am trying to set proxy for APT so I can update.

The server is behind a proxy which is in the domain. I have tried the following in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

1. for FTP, HTTP, https

   ```
   Acquire::HTTP::Proxy "http://[domain\user[:Password02#]@10.1.1.8:8080/";
   ```
2. Also tried

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://domain\user:Password02#]@10.1.1.8:8080/";
   ```
3. Also tried

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http:/user@domain.com:Password02#]@10.1.1.8:8080/";
   ```

I always get the error below:

```
root@canonical:/etc/apt# apt-get update

  407  Proxy Authorization Required

Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does
```

How can I set up my proxy correctly?

Comment: Well, 3. is an invalid URL. Schema and the remainder are not separated by `://`.  Furthermore 3. cannot work because it contains two `@` characters. These are used to separate `username[+password]` from the server name and URI. My guess would be that the issue is the backslash in the user name. And that should be something that I'd expect to be configurable on the proxy server (e.g. by defining a default domain). **Also** if your password or user name has funky characters, that'll probably also cause trouble here. Try to stick to alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@10.1.1.8:8080";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@10.1.1.8:8080";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://user:password@10.1.1.8:8080";
```

Comment: Not so different from the example in the question. Perhaps the actual problem is the backslash in the user name?

Comment: And the domain he has tried to insert at different places.